# View pylint errors using coc and neovim

Tags: neovim, filetype-python, plugin-coc, plugin-python-mode

For the following code there is an error in the gutter, but I don't know how to view the actual message for it.

[image]

Similarly here:

[image]

In the bottom right of the editor are warnings and errors:

[image]

But I don't know how to go about viewing them, in vscode there was a `toggle warnings / errors` screen, is there something similar here?

## Edit

To view the warnings the cursor must within the underlined section, for example:

[image]

I would like to know whether it's possible to view all of these at once.

## Edit 2

I'm not using ALE, just coc, here is my coc config:

```
{
  "coc.preferences.useQuickfixForLocations": true,
  "coc.preferences.snippets.enable": true,
  "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": ["python"],
  // python config
  "python.venvFolders": [".virtualenvs"],
  "python.venvPath" : "~/",
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.jediEnabled": false,
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "python.formatting.blackPath": "~/.virtualenvs/neovim/bin/black",
  "python.sortImports.path": "~/.virtualenvs/neovim/bin/isort",
  "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true
}
```

## Edit 3

It seems that `:CocList diagnostics` will bring up a window that displays a list of all errors within the current file.

From here: https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python/issues/69

[image]

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks, I'm just using `coc`, not ALE

Comment: ( are these supposed to / able to be run together? )

Comment: No idea; I would check the coc docs on detail though. Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble cheers - still bumbling around at the moment to be honest, not too sure what's meant to be used where :)